# How do I charge a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor-charging

So I have a 270uF 350v capacitor that I am trying to charge.

[image: here's the schematic i have to work from]

The schematic shows a the right size for a 22uF, how do I know what size resistor i need to charge it? 
What type of transistor do I need? 
I'm assuming the voltage needs to match the capacitor in order to charge it to full capacity, correct? Short of simply buying a voltage booster is there a fairly simple way to charge this up using a 12V 2A DC power supply?

[image: Here's the capacitor I have:]

Why does it say 350wv instead of 350v?

Sorry for so many questions on my first post. I know these answers are out there somewhere but Google is not being very helpful right now.

Edit: added transformer schematic (I don't actually have the transformer/inductor to test so im I'm not 100% sure if it's correct) I believe it is a tecnically a pulse  transformer

Comment: WV means "Working Voltage". DC is assumed.

Comment: What are the "prongs" the capacitor is connected to?

Comment: @ThePhoton this is supposed to be a schematic for a weak "taser." Quick capacitor discharge, 2-3 second recharge. So the "prongs" will simply be short circuited to discharge the capacitor.

Comment: Is this upconverter to be a flyback design, or just a squarewave driving the transformer?

Answer (score 2):

On the "WV" question, this represents "Working Voltage", which is probably your interpretation of "350V".

For the schematic, what are the pins allocation for the transformer - it's not clear to me, but is important to understand the setup and therefore the spec of the resistor.

Comment: I've edited the post to show the transformer schematic, but I'm beginning to think that whole schematic I have is messed up because it's really not making sense. That should be a 1.5v to approx370v pulse transformer.

Comment: You are correct about the messed up part. That schematic makes no sense at all.

Comment: I concur. Even with those windings, I don't quite see how this would work, much less what that resistor does. 

Consider looking into schematics for Capacitor discharge ignition or Transistorised Ignition. These resemble this circuit in function and allow for the generation of high voltages (which cap be captured in a capacitor using a diode as shown in your schematic). Alternatively, there are many photoflash capacitor charger components that might suit you (e.g. LT3750).